# How to fetch doctrine2 relations conditionally

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities like following:
**1. Customer.php**

```
<?php

//...

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CompanyBundle\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomerAddress", mappedBy="customer")
     */
    private $customerAddresses;

   // ...
}

?>
```

**2. CustomerAddress.php**

```
<?php

//...

/**
 * CustomerAddress
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer_address")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CompanyBundle\Repository\CustomerAddressRepository")
 */
class CustomerAddress
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="customerAddresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomerAddressType", inversedBy="customerAddresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_address_type_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $customerAddressType;

    //...

}
```

**3. CustomerAddressType.php**

```
<?php

//...

/**
 * CustomerAddressType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer_address_type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CompanyBundle\Repository\CustomerAddressTypeRepository")
 */
class CustomerAddressType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomerAddress", mappedBy="customerAddressType")
     */
    private $customerAddresses;

    //...
}
```

Here are the rows from table `customer_address_type`

[image: Here are the rows from table]

I want to get all customer addresses of type either 'BA' or 'SA". So I want to remove all other type except these two. Basically I want to do something similiar like query scope in Laravel.

```
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        // Here I want to filter customer addresses
        // Currently its giving me all
        $customer_address = $customer->getCustomerAddresses();
    }
```

Is it possible to do like so without using custom query?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a custom query? That is what DB systems are for, after all!

Comment: You can't do that without a custom query in your `Repository`.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker because I want reuse that portion of code and also it will help in serialization

Answer (score 0):

You can get an ArrayCollection with all the addresses and then use filter method to get only the ones that you want. You can do it inside the Customer entity so you can reuse it for serialization.

You have to pass a closure to the filter method, and then it iterates over the collection evaluating the closure that should renturn true when you want to include the item in the result or false if not.